# SQL ORACLE - get min row with sequence equal values

Tags: sql, oracle

My have table similar to:

```
MY_DAT   | STATUS
=========|========
1.1.2017 | A 
2.1.2017 | A 
3.1.2017 | A 
4.1.2017 | B 
5.1.2017 | B 
6.1.2017 | A 
7.1.2017 | C 
8.1.2017 | A 
9.1.2017 | A 
10.1.2017| A
```

I want SQL query that by date(**MY_DAT**) return min date with equal **STATUS** without interruption.
Example

```
MY_DAT = '1.1.2017' -> '1.1.2017',A
MY_DAT = '3.1.2017' -> '1.1.2017',A
MY_DAT = '10.1.2017' -> '8.1.2017',A
MY_DAT = '5.1.2017' -> '4.1.2017',B
```

I don't how this sql have to look like.

### EDIT

I need result to be for every date. In this example result have to be:

```
MY_DAT   | STATUS | BEGIN
=========|========|========
1.1.2017 | A      |1.1.2017
2.1.2017 | A      |1.1.2017
3.1.2017 | A      |1.1.2017
4.1.2017 | B      |4.1.2017
5.1.2017 | B      |4.1.2017
6.1.2017 | A      |6.1.2017
7.1.2017 | C      |7.1.2017
8.1.2017 | A      |8.1.2017
9.1.2017 | A      |8.1.2017
10.1.2017| A      |8.1.2017
```

### ANSWER

```
select my_date, status,
       min(my_date) over (partition by grp, status) as begin 
from (select my_date,status ,
          row_number() over(order by my_date) 
          -row_number() over(partition by status order by my_date) as grp 
      from tbl ) t
```

Thanks to [Vamsi Prabhala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3431869/vamsi-prabhala)

Comment: Column MY_DAT's data type?

Comment: MY_DAT is type DATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a difference of row numbers approach to assign groups to consecutive rows with same status. (Run the inner query to see this.). After this, it is just a `group by` operation to get the `min` date.

```
select status,min(my_date)
from (select my_date,status
      ,row_number() over(order by my_date)
       -row_number() over(partition by status order by my_date) as grp
      from tbl
     ) t 
group by grp,status
```

Comment: It is almost that for what i looking for. But how i can see result for every date or white WHERE clause and see result about '10.1.2017'? That is because I want to see the result for every date.

Comment: I found the answer. Instead "GROUP BY" in external part of query we can use one more "partition by grp, status".  The final query is
"select my_date, status,min(my_date) over (partition by grp, status) as begin
from (select my_date,status
      ,row_number() over(order by my_date)
       -row_number() over(partition by status order by my_date) as grp
      from tbl
     ) t "

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
SELECT status, min(my_dat)
  FROM dates
 GROUP BY status
```

OK, then what about this?

```
SELECT *
  FROM dates
 INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT status, min(my_dat)
    FROM dates
    GROUP BY status
) sub
    ON dates.status = sub.status
```

Comment: "... without interruption."

Comment: This will return min date in table. How is show in example - I need min date on sequence of dates with equal status. With your query i will always receive  '1.1.2017' for status 'A', but i need when my_dat='10.1.2017' result to be ''8.1.2017'' because 8.10, 9.10 and 10.10 are 'A' and 7.10 is not 'A'(it is 'B'). We can look at this like 'Sometimes I am rich and sometimes i am not. Now i am rich! From when I am rich without change my status'

Comment: No, result is the same expect that it return date and min date. Again it return '1.1.2017' when MY_DAT is '10.1.2017' but result have to be '8.1.2017' because '7.1.2017' is interruption(for date '7.1.2017' status is 'B' but in '10.1.2017' status is 'A')